# PHP Mongo Full Text Search (error "can't find ns")

Tags: php, mongodb, full-text-search

## The Problem

When I try to run a full text search against my Mongo database, I receive the following error.

```
{"ok":0,"errmsg":"can't find ns"}
```

I have tried finding anything online to refer to ns with no luck. I assume its an indexing issue...

I can confirm my index is there and I can even run a full text search from Mongo commandline and it works! Just not via PHP.

## Setup

- MongoDB v 2.4.5
- PHP Mongo Driver v.1.4.2
- PHP 5.5.9

Started Mongo (version 2.4.5) with textSearchEnabled. PHP Mongo Driver 1.4.2

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

#### Database

- DB Name = aero
- Collection = https_aero_guides

#### PHP Code

Here is my code

```
$this->mongo_db->_connection->admin->command(
    array(
       "setParameter" => 1, 
       "textSearchEnabled" => true
    )
);
$this->mongo_db->_connection->aero->https_aero_guides->ensureIndex(
    array(
        'title' => 'text'
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'title_text',
        'weights' => array('title' => 100)
    )
);

$results = $this->mongo_db->_connection->aero->command(
    array(
        'text' => 'https_aero_guides',
        'search' => 'hello',
        'limit' => 5
    )
);
```

#### Data searching against

Database has the following rows

```
[
{ title : "hello" }, 
{ title : "waynes" }, 
{ title : "world" }
]
```

#### Mongo Indexes

```
> db.https_aero_guides.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
    "ns" : "aero.https_aero_guides",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "aero.https_aero_guides",
        "name" : "title_text",
        "weights" : {
            "title" : 100
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 1
    }
]
```

#### Mongo Indexes

Comment: If you want to do text search, use MongoDB >= 2.6, where text search is actually a fully-fledged feature. You can use it through regular find queries instead of commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wdberkeley you were correct. Upgrading mongo fixed our issue.

Cheers!